# alter html of given script

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova

I am using a script for a currency converter within phonegap.Code below:

```
<div id="Money" style='width:100%;height:90%;'>
    <script src="http://www.transfermate.com/en/exchange_rates_api.asp"></script> 
</div>
```

I am new to all of this, so it may be a silly question, but is there any way to alter the html in it? Basically I need to reduce the width of a text field and button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use CSS, like this:

```css
#curr_amount {
    width: 50px;
}
```

Luckily embedded content is not within iframe, so you can style it easily with normal CSS on the host page.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pmt7ss3x/

Comment: thanks for your response. I can see it works in the js fiddle but it didnt work in phonegap

Comment: Check your styles, CSS rules, etc. It should work, it's the same as styling any other element on your page.

Answer (score 1):

if you inspect the text field using your browser's developer tools you can get the id of the text box element. the id of the first one is curr_amount. therefore you can use css like this -

```
#curr_amount {width: 100px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about phone gap but this is general.

After the above div tag open a script tag and refer to the elements by name or id and then using the style attribute you can change the properties.